# Regex, R, and Commas

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm having some trouble with a regex string in R. I'm trying to use regex to extract the tags from a string (scraped from the web) as follows:

```
str <- "\n\n\n    \n\n\n      “Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”\n    ―\n    Dr. Seuss\n\n\n\n\n   \n     tags:\n       attributed-no-source,\n       cry,\n       crying,\n       experience,\n       happiness,\n       joy,\n       life,\n       misattributed-dr-seuss,\n       optimism,\n       sadness,\n       smile,\n       smiling\n   \n   \n     176513 likes\n   \n\n\n\n\nLike\n\n"

# Why doesn't this work at all?
stringr::str_match(str, "tags:(.+)\\d")

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] NA   NA  

# Why just the first tag? What happens at the comma?
stringr::str_match(str, "tags:\n(.+)")

      [,1]                                  [,2]                          
[1,] "tags:\n       attributed-no-source," "       attributed-no-source,"
```

So two questions -- why doesn't my first idea work, and why doesn't the second capture through the end of the string, rather than just the first comma?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain what your desired result is.

Comment: Did you meant `str_match(str, "tags:[^0-9]*[0-9]*")` for the first case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `stringr` regex flavor is that of ICU. Unlike TRE, `.` does not match  line breaks in ICU regex patterns.

So, a possible fix is to use `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier that makes `.` match any char including line break chars - at the start of your patterns:

```
str_match(str, "(?s)tags:(.+)\\d")
```

and

```
str_match(str, "(?s)tags:\n(.+)")
```

However, I feel as if you need to get all the strings below `tags:` as separate matches. I suggest using a base R `regmatches` / `gregexpr` with a PCRE regex like

```
(?:\G(?!\A),?|tags:)\R\h*\K[^\s,]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8BCU9Y/1/) on your data.

- `(?:\G(?!\A),?|tags:)` - match the end of the previous successful match with 1 or 0 `,` after it (`\G(?!\A),?`) or (`|`) `tags:` substring
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `\h*`  - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far
- `[^\s,]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `,`

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/jjFkf3):

```
str <- "\n\n\n    \n\n\n      “Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”\n    ―\n    Dr. Seuss\n\n\n\n\n   \n     tags:\n       attributed-no-source,\n       cry,\n       crying,\n       experience,\n       happiness,\n       joy,\n       life,\n       misattributed-dr-seuss,\n       optimism,\n       sadness,\n       smile,\n       smiling\n   \n   \n     176513 likes\n   \n\n\n\n\nLike\n\n"
reg <- "(?:\\G(?!\\A),?|tags:)\\R\\h*\\K[^\\s,]+"
vals <- regmatches(str, gregexpr(reg, str, perl=TRUE))
unlist(vals)
```

Result:

```
[1] "attributed-no-source" "cry" "crying" 
[4] "experience" "happiness" "joy" 
[7] "life" "misattributed-dr-seuss" "optimism" 
[10] "sadness" "smile" "smiling"
```